# Read file, reverse it and write it to another file

Tags: c, file-io

We have got a text file which contains 10 million integers in a sorted order. Need to write a program in C to reverse these numbers and write it to a separate file. Which data structure to use and how to copy such a huge data in memory? And for reversing shall i use fseek or store in some data structure and then reverse?
Please help.

Comment: Is each line a unique integer, or are there multiple integers per line, (if so, how are they seperated)

Comment: reverse each integer individually or the file data means last integer in the first place and so on ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it through a C program only? A scripting language like perl, or using basic tools would be more appropriate(and easier)

Comment: @Omkant- Last integer of the file in 1st position and so on.

Comment: @DesertIce-Yes i need to do it through c. Understanding file handling in C/C++

Comment: @Abhishekkumar: Why do you not break you file into several files...you required simple parsing(reverse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run this on a basic desktop system, no special data structure other than a (dynamic) array is needed.

Just allocate space for e.g. 1,000 numbers initially, startl loading, and double the allocation size when it runs out. This will grow the array like so:

```
1,000 -> 2,000 -> 4,000 -> 8,000 -> 16,000 -> 32,000 ->
```

64,000 -> 128,000 -> 256,000 -> 512,000 -> 1,024,000

so it will do 10 calls to `realloc()` which really should be fine.

Once you have the numbers in an array, just loop over it backwards and print each number to the output file.

Of course, you can use the fact that you know that there's a million numbers to your advantage, and set the initial size appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use a fixed-size buffer (of the filesystem's block size) and to read blocks from the end of the file, then writing it to new file reading the buffer backwards.

This way you don't have to `realloc` any buffers (it's a costly operation, though it may be ok with files of megabyte size).